# proving a limit of a function by definition

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Consider $f: \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$ defined by
$$
f(z) =
\begin{cases}
z^3 + 2z &\text{if } z \ne i \\
3 + 2i &\text{if } z = i
\end{cases} $$

Prove that
$$
\lim_{z \to i} f(z) = i
$$
using the definition of the limit.

I have tried to find a relation between $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: Please format your answer using MathJax; [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may be helpful. As it stands, it's very difficult to read.

Comment: I have formatted the mathematics to be more readable.  Unfortunately, as it's written here, you are trying to prove something that **isn't true** since $\lim_{z \to i} \left( z^2 + 2z \right) = -1 + 2i$.

Comment: I am sorry sammy black it is (z^3) not (z^2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have
$|z^3+2z| = |z-i||z^2+iz+1|=|z-i||(z-i+i)^2+i(z-i+i)+1|$
         $=|z-i||(z-i)^2+2i(z-i)-1+i(z-i)-1+1| $
         $ \le  $$|z-i||z-i|^2+3|i||z-i|+1 $
  $let    $          $\delta = 1$
       $|z^3+2z|$  $\lt $$\delta$$( 1^2+3 +1 ) =5\delta $

$Hence$
$\delta= min ${1,$\epsilon/5$ }$ $

I find it finally